# Unit testing node.js model code accessing mongodb, without actually accessing the database

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking

For example, I have the code below:

```
var db = require('./_mongo.js');
module.exports = {
    check: function (cb) {
        var content = {};
        content.collection = 'counters';
        content.query = {_id: 'ping'};
        content.columns = {};
        db.read(content, function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                cb(-1);
            }
            else {
                cb(0);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

How do I write a unit test for the 'check' function, without actually accessing the database, while at the same time checking if I am able to code the correct 'content' variable being passed to the read method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock an entire module with a mock framework, like [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/):

```
var db = sinon.mock(require('_mongo.js'))
```

I would not recommend to mock database access, it could require you to code all possible responses...

It would be best if you would hide the database access behind an abstracted service layer and mock that layer.

For example, you can create a database access layer in this way:

```
var db = require('./_mongo.js');
module.exports = {
    //this is a mockable method
    getCounter: function (id, callback) {
        var content = {};
        content.collection = 'counters';
        content.query = {_id: id};
        content.columns = {};
        db.read(content, callback);
    }
};

//and then using it
module.exports = {
    check: function (cb) {
        //access the actual method or the mock
        da.getCounter('ping', function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                cb(-1);
            }
            else {
                cb(0);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[test-studio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/test-studio) provides mechanisms for stubbing out module dependencies. It also supports things like executing individual or groups of tests and stepping node-inspector into individual tests.

Read more about it [here](http://www.danderson00.com/2014/05/test-studio-unit-testing-for-nodejs-how.html).